# Redirecting non-www to www on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, iis-8

I have added a ASP.NET website as an application under Default Web Sites in IIS 8. This website without the www is redirected to a Apache HTTP Server Test Page. So I tried to redirect non-www to www of my website, but that is not happening.

```
  <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect non-www to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abcdefgh.in/{R:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="abcdefgh.in" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
 </rewrite>
```

Is it because, the website is added as an application under Default Web Site? are there any other options that has to be enabled? I have just started learning ASP.NET and IIS. Any help will be really useful. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "This website without the www is redirected to a Apache HTTP Server Test Page" ? Where is this redirection performed ? At DNS level ? If so, you should start with updating your DNS entry